# Disable unknown ftp server

Tags: 12.04, sftp

I am sitting in front of a Ubuntu 12.4. which is running an SFTP server, that I want to stop / disable. The problem is that I don't know what the name of the ftp sever is. How do I find that out program is providing the SFTP sever?

**[update]** 
It seems like vsftd is not installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get -s install vsftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vsftpd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Inst vsftpd (2.3.5-1ubuntu2 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
Conf vsftpd (2.3.5-1ubuntu2 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
```

Comment: Do you want to stop the server permanently or just disable it until you reboot your machine?

Comment: You can get a list of programs listening on ports by running "sudo netstat -lnp --protocol=inet" in a terminal. Maybe this would help you to identify what SFTP server is running on your system, as I understand the SFTP server would be listening on port 22.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the Server permanently you should use this:

`sudo apt-get remove vsftpd`

If you want to set rights such as read/wright rights you should edit the config file located here:

`/etc/vsftpd.conf` to edit the `vsftpd.conf` file use this `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf`

**UPDATE**

Try this:

As **Daniel Yuste Aroca** mentioned use `netstat -lnp --protocol=inet` to check what server is still running.

Open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file: `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Then find line that read as follows: `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

Remove or comment out line by prefixing #:

`# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

Save and close the file. Restart sshd service:
 `# /etc/init.d/sshd restart`

Comment: `/etc/vsftpd.conf` does not exist on the machine.

Comment: Did you run the command `sudo apt-get remove vsftpd`?

Comment: I did not enter `sudo apt-get remove vsftpd`, but I tried `sudo apt-get -s install vsftpd` and it seems vsftpd is not installed. See also update of my question.